# extract date from string in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I extract date from such strings in excel?

female in 1  2014-07-15T16:26:34.2343442+01:00 PointEvent

I have this data and in the end I want  to have: female in 1; and in another cell : 16:26:34

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have more than just this one line of data, you may wish to consider using Excel's [Text Import Wizard](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-import-wizard-HP010102244.aspx).  This will save you lots of time and hassle trying to use formulas to extract the data from your string.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing for some padding before "female" and extracting the time and converting it to an excel time such that you can sort and calculate with that column

Your string in column A1
"female in 1 2014-07-15T16:26:34.2343442+01:00 PointEvent"

In B1
`=MID(A1,FIND("female",A1),11)`

In C1
`=TIME(MID(A1,FIND("female",A1)+23,2),MID(A1,FIND("female",A1)+26,2),MID(A1,FIND("female",A1)+29,2))`